# Getting h5py using Enthought Canopy Express (MacOSX)

Tags: python, macos, enthought

I'm using Enthought Canopy Express, and I am trying to use the h5py package.

I tried directly installing h5py by typing the following command in Terminal:

```
pip install h5py
```

And got the following error:

```
h5py/api_compat.h:27:10: fatal error: 'hdf5.h' file not found
```

Any ideas about how to proceed? I'd really like to stick with Enthought Canopy if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you install Canopy Express or full? If Express, are you a subscriber? If yes, did you try installing h5py in package manager?

Comment: Ugh. I only have Canopy Express, and it appears that I have to upgrade and pay to get h5py.  Any suggestions about how to get it without the upgrade?  Thanks!

Comment: Note: I'm not using Canopy for commercial purposes--just using it to learn Python.

Comment: If you are a student or staff at a degree-granting institution (including K-12), you are eligible for a free academic license. See https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/academic/

Comment: I tried your suggestion, Jonathan.  Hopefully it'll work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming here.

Open Canopy Terminal through enthought canopy
type

```
sudo enpkg h5py
```

and continue installation.
Give in your enthought credentials (which you can register for free as suggested by Jonathan above) and it will be installed.